# How can I implement a fuzzy search across each value of a dictionary in a multiple dictionary list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries. I am trying to implement a 'fuzzy' search of said dictionary values and have the full dictionary returned.

Therefore, if I have a list of dicts as follows:

```
[
{"Name":"Arnold", "Age":"52", "Height":"160"}, 
{"Name":"Donald", "Age":"52", "Height":"161"}, 
{"Name":"Trevor", "Age":"22", "Height":"150"}
]
```

A search term of "**nol**" should return

```
{"Name":"Arnold", "Age":"52", "Height":"160"}
```

While a search term of "**52**" should return:

```
{"Name":"Arnold", "Age":"52", "Height":"160"} 
{"Name":"Donald", "Age":"52", "Height":"161"}
```

I understand that I can search for values at a particular key using iteritems, I'm just not clear on how to search across all key/values in a dictionary (without knowing the keyname), and then return said dictionary if there is a match in any. Is this possible in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my version, which doesn't save all the results at the same time in a list, but instead generates them as needed.

```
import itertools

database = [
    {"Name":"Arnold", "Age":"52", "Height":"160"}, 
    {"Name":"Donald", "Age":"52", "Height":"161"}, 
    {"Name":"Trevor", "Age":"22", "Height":"150"},
]

def search(s):
    s = s.lower() # it is a nice feature to ignore case
    for item in database:
        if any(s in v.lower() for v in item.values()): # if any value contains s
            yield item # spit out the item — this is a generator function

# iterate over at most 5 first results
for result in itertools.islice(search("52"), 5):   
    print(result)
```

```
{'Height': '160', 'Age': '52', 'Name': 'Arnold'}
{'Height': '161', 'Age': '52', 'Name': 'Donald'}
```

Comment: @user714852 You can also just put `()`s around the comprehension to produce a generator... `(d for d in l if any("nol" in v for v in d.values()))`. You don't need to define a new function.

Answer (score 4):

You can use something like

```
>>> l = [
... {"Name":"Arnold", "Age":"52", "Height":"160"}, 
... {"Name":"Donald", "Age":"52", "Height":"161"}, 
... {"Name":"Trevor", "Age":"22", "Height":"150"}
... ]
>>>
>>> [d for d in l if any("nol" in v for v in d.values())]
[{'Age': '52', 'Name': 'Arnold', 'Height': '160'}]
>>>
>>> [d for d in l if any("52" in v for v in d.values())]
[{'Age': '52', 'Name': 'Arnold', 'Height': '160'}, {'Age': '52', 'Name': 'Donald', 'Height': '161'}]
```

Comment: Dude that is amazing! Simple and it works! Any thoughts on how I could restrict the number of results returned? So the last query only spat out 1 result?

Comment: @user714852 You could slice the returned list: `returned_list[0:1]`.

Comment: @user714852 `next(d for d in l if any("52" in v for v in d.values()))` returns the first result without generating the rest, unlike list slicing (but raises `StopIteration` if there are 0 results, which is not a problem).

Comment: @OlehPrypin I like the idea of stopping the iteration. The list of dicts I have is quite large and ideally I'd only like retrieve a few results (e.g. 5) before returning them.

Answer (score 1):

Another slightly different option:

```
searchTerm = "nol"
unusedCharacter = "\n"  # This should be a character that will never appear in your search string.
# Changed this to a generator to avoid searching the whole dict all at once:
results = (d for d in l if searchTerm in unusedCharacter.join(d.values()))

# Produce a limited number of results:
limitedResults = []
maxResults = 5
for k, result in enumerate(results):
    if k == maxResults:
        break
    limitedResults.append(result)
```

Comment: Maybe join it with `'\ufff0'` or something, not `''`, so you don't get unexisting matches like "21" in "52160Arnold"

Comment: @Oleh Mm, good point - didn't think of that case.  I chose a newline, because unicode frightens me.  The OP can decide what character is least likely to appear in the text.

Comment: @Brionius thanks for your input - I love the idea of speed as these lists are quite long. I'll have to think closely as to the least likely character - as the dictionaries contain quite a lot of information - names, emails, numbers, etc. Any idea on the limiting of the output to say 5 results?

Comment: @user714852 In order to limit the results in a time-efficient way, I changed the list comprehension to a generator comprehension, then builds a list of at most the desired size from the results.